# Mat-icon does not show icon

Tags: angular, angular-material, icons

I love angular material's design, but using it can be a pain.  The site shows an example using

```
<mat-icon>home</mat-icon>
```

However, when I do the same thing in my project, I just see the text "home".

I don't see where I need to do anything other than import MatIconModule.

Does anyone have a clue?

I'm using angular material v8.0.1. I also installed material-design-icons v 3.0.1. and have this in my index.html.  (i did one at a time)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://storage.googleapis.com/non-spec-apps/mio-icons/latest/outline.css">
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need remove

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://storage.googleapis.com/non-spec-apps/mio-icons/latest/outline.css">
```

and change to

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: with angular 10 and latest material this solution is not working for me !

Answer (score 4):

In my case some icons were working, some not. Switching from

```
<mat-icon>home</mat-icon>
```

to

```
<span class="material-icons">home</span>
```

solved the problem.

Comment: Why does that happen? I supposed that's exactly my problem but I cannot confirm once this problem happens in a third party plugin that uses mat-icon

Answer (score 1):

Angular material 8.0.1 requires material design icons to be included as follows

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

Also you will need to import mat-icon module as

```
import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';
```

Then in your component template file you can use

```
<mat-icon>home</mat-icon>
```