# how to create button with icon and text using angular material?

Tags: css

I m customising angular material for my project.
I m facing alignment issues with padding-left

My Result:

[image: My result]

Expected result:

[image: Expected result]

And here is my code:

```css
.mat-flat-button {
  line-height: 28px !important;
  padding: 0 12px !important;
  font-weight: 400 !important;
}
```

```html
<button mat-flat-button color="primary">
  <mat-icon color="white">add</mat-icon>
  Create
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the button text in a `span` tag and add the following properties to it:

```css
button {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-right: 12px;
}
```

```html
<button mat-flat-button color="primary">
  <mat-icon color="white">add</mat-icon> 
  <span>Create</span>
</button>
```

### Edit:

Changes in the code are done to run this snippet on this website:

Replacing `<mat-icon color="white">add</mat-icon>` with `<span color="white" class="material-icons">add</span>` (Credits: **[krmld](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61713265/17235431)**)

```css
button {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-right: 12px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <button mat-flat-button color="primary">
  <span color="white" class="material-icons">add</span> 
  <span>Create</span>
 </button>
</body>
```

Comment: It did nt worked as expected! So I edited my question to get more clarification

Comment: @Vignesh does setting padding-left of the button to zero work?

Comment: It didnt worked because of :
.mat-flat-button {
  padding: 0 12px !important;
}

Comment: @Vignesh then add the same padding to the right of the text, I have updated my answer, does this work?

Comment: No .. it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using the following css styles

```css
.mat-button,
.mat-flat-button {
  padding: 0 12px !important;
  line-height: 28px !important;
  font-weight: 400 !important;
  font-size: small !important;
}

.mat-icon {
  height: inherit !important;
  width: inherit !important;
}

.mat-flat-button>.mat-button-wrapper>mat-icon {
  margin-left: -4px !important;
  margin-right: 4px !important;
  font-size: large !important;

}

.mat-button-toggle-label-content {
  line-height: 20px !important;
}
```